# Intuition: Inclusion of balls leads to reverse inclusion of norm?

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces

Suppose we have a banach space $X$ with two norms $||\cdot||_1, ||\cdot||_2$. Let $B_1 \equiv \{ x \in X : ||x||_1 \leq 1 \}$ and similarly for $B_2$.

If one is given the inclusion $(\star): B_1 \subseteq B_2$, then one can prove that $||x||_2 \leq ||x||_1$:

- Let $x \in X$. Consider $\hat x \equiv x / ||x||_1$. Since $\hat x \in B_1$ by construction, $\hat x \in B_2$ by $(\star)$. Thus $||\hat x||_2 \leq 1$. Substituting $\hat x$, $|| x / ||x||_1 ||_2 \leq 1$, which on rearrangement gives $||x ||_2  \leq ||x||_1$.

But geometrically, I am confused! Why does the $||\cdot||_2 \leq ||\cdot||_1$ create the *reverse* situation where $B_1 \subseteq B_2$?

Is the idea that for a given vector $x$, since the second norm "underweights" the vector $x$ ($||\cdot||_2 \leq ||\cdot||_1$), and thus "more vectors" sneak into the unit ball $B_2$, and thus $B_1 \subseteq B_2$?

I would like to have more ways to think about this, since I still feel unsure about my chain of intuitive reasoning.

Comment: Big norms have small balls.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It creates the "reverse" situation because the inequality $\|\cdot\|_2\leq\|\cdot\|_1$ means that if $x$ belongs to the unit ball of the norm $\|\cdot\|_1$ then it also belongs to the unit ball of $\|\cdot\|_2$.