# Intuition: Inclusion of balls leads to reverse inclusion of norm, even upon rescaling?

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces

Suppose we have a banach space $X$ with two norms $||\cdot||_1, ||\cdot||_2$. Let $B_1 (r) \equiv \{ x \in X : ||x||_1 \leq r \}$ and similarly for $B_2$.

If one is given the inclusion $(\star): B_1(r)  \subseteq B_2(s) $, then one can prove that $||x||_2 \leq s/r ||x||_1$:

- Let $x \in X$. Consider $\hat x \equiv r x / ||x||_1$. Since $\hat x \in B_1$ by construction, $\hat x \in B_2$ by $(\star)$. Thus $||\hat x||_2 \leq s$. Substituting $\hat x$, $|| r x / ||x||_1 ||_2 \leq s$, which on rearrangement gives $||x ||_2  \leq s/r ||x||_1$.

Now I am confused, because I would have expected that depending on the values of $s, r$, I should be able to either lower or upper bound $||x||_2$ by $||x||_1$. But it appears that *regardless* of the values of $s, r$, $||x||_2$ is *always upper bounded* by $||x||_1$. Isn't this strange?

Why is the fact that a unit ball $B_1(1)$, *arbitrarily* rescaled by $r$ getting trapped in the ball $B_2(s)$ allow us to upper bound $||x||_2$ by $||x||_1$?

Intuitively, I do understand what happens if both balls are unit radius. Then the containment of the balls tells us that one of the norms increases *faster*, and thus its unit ball is *smaller*. But in this case, we are comparing balls of *different* radii ($r$, $s$), so I don't see how this analysis applies any more.

Help with intuition on how to think about this scenario would be very appreciated.

Comment: You received an answer yesyerday [in the case of unit balls](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4749092). Now, simply realize that the ball (centered at $0$) of radius $r$ for some norm $N$ is nothing but the unit ball for the norm $N/r.$

Comment: @AnneBauval In that scenario, _both_ balls were unit balls. In this scenario, even upon rescaling, one of the balls is non-unit, so I am unsure how to visualize this.

Comment: @AnneBauval Ah, I see, you are saying that I should consider the rescaled norm $s/r ||x||_2$ as a _new_ norm $||x||_3 \equiv s/r ||x||_2$?

Comment: Yes. Or rescale both norms.

Comment: Thanks, I now believe this! Would you like to post the comment as an answer so I can mark it as accepted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You received an answer yesterday [in the case of unit balls](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4749092). Now, simply realize that the ball (centered at $0$) of radius $r$ for some norm $N$ is nothing but the unit ball for the norm $N/r.$